# Why output text file is not being created after the code is deployed in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, deployment, file-io, fstream

I wrote a simple code to print the square of input number on a text file. I included fstream package in visual studio IDE, the solution gets build, the text is created where my solution is after executing the file in command prompt. But when I deploy my code and then I install it on another computer, it runs and takes the input in command prompt but doesn't create the text file. Where is the text file gone?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream outfile("out.txt");
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    outfile << n * n;
}
```

Comment: * text file is created(2nd line)

Comment: What is the current directory when your program is running?  That's where the file will go.  Also, check for error after opening it.

Comment: When you run your program in Visual Studio the default folder is the one containing the project file. This is set in the debugging settings of your executable project. The exact setting is: `Project Properties->Debugging->Working Directory` The default is set as $(ProjectDir) which is a Visual Studio variable containing the path of project folder.

Comment: ***But when I deploy my code and then I install it on another computer, it runs and takes the input in command prompt but doesn't create the text file. Where is the text file gone?*** Are you installing to the `C:\Program Files` folder? If so UAC will prevent you from writing files there.

Answer (score 0):

Nothings wrong with your code. Check your file directory, it usually located at C/Users/User/Source/repos/Yourfilename/Yourfilename or where the cpp files located.